# Question About Job Posting (M/F)

Tags: discussion, jobs

There is a job posting I saw on the side:

> Wanted: Python Developer (m/f) at Ableton AG (Berlin, Germany)

Two things come to mind:

- "Male or Female", which just seems odd, or
- "Monday through Friday", which seems more relevant, but also strange to put in the job title.

Anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your first thought was the right one: It stands for Male/Female. In German job offers, the term `(m/w)` *(männlich/weiblich -> male/female)* is used.

This comes from the fact that in German, nouns like job descriptions have both a male and a female form (e.g. *Lehrer* and *Lehrerin* for *teacher*). Since companies want to show that they are open to male and female applicants, but always writing both forms is a waste of time/space/letters/bandwidth, the form `Job Title (m/w)` came to be.

The advertisement you read was obviously translated by someone who didn't think of the fact that English does not have any gender distinction in job titles.

Comment: That's not anywhere near as cool as I was hoping.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for satisfying my curiosity, which demands I find out thins that I really don't need to know :-)

Comment: @TheTXI, actually, that is much *cooler* than I was hoping. I don't care if he's making it up. That answer is awesome. For the record, I don't think he's making it up.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to flag these ads so they can update their listings.

Comment: English doesn't have gender distinction in job titles? How about stewardess or waitress? :)

Comment: That sucks, it's kind of discriminatory if you ask me.

Comment: @Javier: How so? I think it is the exact opposite: Non discriminatory.

Comment: @Treb well on the one hand it is very clear what gender they want to certain position which is fine, but on the other hand why would you even restrict a job to a certain gender?

Comment: @Javier: I think you misunderstand the intention: They explicitly want both genders to apply, hence m/w (male/female). BTW, you won't find any job posting asking for only male or only female applicants in Germany - that company could easily be sued for discrimination.